# Proof of invariance of scalar product under rotations, using index notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, notation, linear-algebra

So I have got the following question:

> Show that the scalar product of two cartesian vectors $p_i\cdot q_i$
>   is invariant under coordinate transformations (orthogonal
>   transformations)

Now I know how to do this using ket notiation:
$$\langle x,y\rangle=x^T y \\ \therefore \langle Ox,Oy\rangle = (Ox)^T O\ y = x^TO^T O \ y = x^T I y = x^T y = \langle x,y\rangle$$ 
where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix. 
Now the solution to the question above was given to me as:
$$O_{ij}p_jO_{ik}q_k = \delta ^{i}_{k}p_jq_k = p_jq_j$$

I am struggling to understand the second step of this solution, where does Kronecker delta symbol comes from (I know that it has to do something with orthogonal matrices and swapping the terms in the first expression). How is the second step related to the same operation in ket notation?

Comment: How do you write $OO^T=1$ in index notation?

Comment: Would it be $(O^TO)^{j} _i = \delta ^{j} _{i}$?

Comment: ... and what is $(O^TO)^j_i$ in index notation?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $O^TO=I$, as you wrote in your first line. Since $I$ is diagonal, its components are $0$ except when row=column, so

$$I_{ij}=\delta _{ij}$$

Writing $O^TO=I$ in matrix notation gives (with a sum over i)

$$(O^T)_{ji}O_{ik}=\delta_{jk}$$

Now just replace $(O^T)_{ji}=O_{ij}$:

$$O_{ij}O_{ik}=\delta_{jk}$$

Plugging that into the equation gives the equality you asked about.